# (Devanagari Font) How to ensure all parts of the text are visible in a <select>?

Tags: html, css, devanagari

I'm using a Google font `Noto Sans` to render English text along with Hindi (Devanagari) in a `<select>`
But some of the Hindi characters seem to be cut off from the top, like in the snippet below:
(The actual text to be rendered is shown below the `<select>`)

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#sel")
, printOption = () => {
  const index = select.selectedIndex, selectedText = select.options[index].text
  document.querySelector("#text").innerText = selectedText
}

select.addEventListener("change", printOption)
printOption()
```

```css
body { padding: 15px; font-family: 'Noto Sans'; }
select, div { font-size: 36px; }
select:focus{ outline: none; }

/* The below rules do not seem to work */
select{
  /* padding: 15px; */
  /* height: 70px; */
  /* line-height: 50px; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" />
<select id="sel">
  <option selected value="1">कोविड 19 केस / Covid 19 Cases</option>
  <option value="2">लिंग अनुपात / Sex Ratio</option>
  <option value="3">वन क्षेत्र / Forest Area</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div id="text"></div>
```

What could be the fix for the same?
I've tried a few properties (mentioned in the CSS code) which didn't give desired results.

Comment: You can use bootstrap dropdown if thats not a limitation

Comment: @user2993464 Would you consider adding an example as an answer?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bulletproofscripts/e5afokhg/

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean; its an alternative. I'm more interested in knowing why the issue occurs natively, and how to solve it without an external library.

Comment: the only workaround i can see is use style font-variant: all-petite-caps; but it will make all smallcase letters to uppercase letters

Comment: I see, it could probably work if I needed only Hindi text since there are no capital/small letters in Hindi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "included" `Noto Sans` in your page but you're not using the font on the select element! So:

The select element is rendered using **Arial** (user agent stylesheet). The characters not present in Arial are rendered using **Nirmala UI** - a fallback font chosen by the browser or OS:

[image: rendered fonts]

The line height of the select element will be that of Arial. But each font has its own *normal* line height and the fallback font seems to require a taller line height in order to display the characters fully so it gets clipped.

The solution is simple: use the **Noto Sans** font on select element which seems to contain all the characters you want to display:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
}
select {
  /* using inherit instead of explicit font name */
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: medium;
}
select:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
select:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" />

<select>
  <option selected value="1">कोविड 19 केस / Covid 19 Cases</option>
  <option value="2">लिंग अनुपात / Sex Ratio</option>
  <option value="3">वन क्षेत्र / Forest Area</option>
</select>
<br>
<select>
  <option selected value="1">कोविड 19 केस / Covid 19 Cases</option>
  <option value="2">लिंग अनुपात / Sex Ratio</option>
  <option value="3">वन क्षेत्र / Forest Area</option>
</select>
<br>
<select>
  <option selected value="1">कोविड 19 केस / Covid 19 Cases</option>
  <option value="2">लिंग अनुपात / Sex Ratio</option>
  <option value="3">वन क्षेत्र / Forest Area</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, seems like a rookie mistake now. Although after adding the font to `<select>`, there seems to be clipping on the lower end eg. on the option `लिंग अनुपात / Sex Ratio`. Any ideas to prevent/resolve that?

Comment: @anurag seems like there is no gap between `नु` and bottom of linebox inside the font so there is not much you can do about it.